# How can I avoid auto-incrementing on update of duplicate key?

Tags: mysql, sql

Take a look at this query:

```
insert into `admin_config`(name)
values ('cached_branch_products_2')
on duplicate key update value = 1
```

There are two possibility which can be happened. Either `insert` or `update`. When the `insert` fires (executes), then a new row will be added to the table and naturally the `AUTO_INCREMENT` will be increased. Ok, all fine.

But when the `update` fires (executes), `AUTO_INCREMENT` will be increased either. Why? And how can I avoid that?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. Is it a problem when the `AUTO_INCREMENT` increases?

Comment: @Vatev Well, nope, It cannot be known as a problem. Just it makes a gap in integration of ID ordering which gives me feeling bad.

Comment: Looks like a [REPLACE INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) isn't an option either. Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94a90e393f4f955f95c81e0e32a32be1)*. I wonder when they'll add MERGE to MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about it.  Auto-increment columns are not guaranteed to be gapless.  In addition to this situation, you deletes and transaction rollbacks will also put them out of order.  In other databases, parallelization and optimization also result in gaps.

Basically, just get used to it.  The purpose of such a column is to provide a unique integer id to each row.  And that works, regardless of gaps.  These ids do capture insertion order.

Trying to create a gapless sequence for this purpose would be very expensive, basically requiring locking the entire table for every insert and delete.  That could significantly affect the performance of some applications.  So the rules are relaxed a bit to provide what is really needed, even if the results do not meet everyone's aesthetic standards.

Comment: 100% agreed. Transaction rollbacks will also leave gaps. It is a pointless exercise to worry about it, or try preventing it.